# Extract string from data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Python and I would like to extract a string data from my data frame. Here is my data frame:
[image]
Which state has the most counties in it?

Unfortunately I could not extract a string! Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')

def answer_five():
    return census_df[census_df['COUNTY']==census_df['COUNTY'].max()]['STATE']
answer_five()
```

Comment: Please don't post images to share data. You can post the output of `df.head()` and format it as code.

Comment: You should create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): make sure you provide a minimal example that we can actually import to play with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of counties per state using python {census}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523185/count-number-of-counties-per-state-using-python-census)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import pandas as pd

census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')

def answer_five():
    """
    Returns the 'STATE' corresponding to the max 'COUNTY' value
    """
    max_county = census_df['COUNTY'].max()
    s = census_df.loc[census_df['COUNTY']==max_county, 'STATE']
    return s

answer_five()
```

This should output a `pd.Series` object featuring the `'STATE'` value(s) where `'COUNTY'` is maxed. If you only want the value and not the `Series` (as your question stated, and since in your image there's only 1 max value for COUNTY) then `return s[0]` (instead of `return s`) should do.

Comment: [Google search](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=Which+US+state+has+the+most+counties+in+it&oq=Which+US+state+has+the+most+counties+in+it&aqs=chrome..69i57.10895j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) says `The number of counties per state ranges from the 3 counties of Delaware to the 254 counties of Texas.` but your query returns `Virginia`. I think we need `groupby('STNAME')['COUNTY']`

Comment: correct answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523185/count-number-of-counties-per-state-using-python-census#40523367)

Answer (score 0):

```
def answer_five():
   return census_df.groupby('STNAME')['COUNTY'].nunique().idxmax()
```

You can aggregate data using group by state name, then get count on unique counties and return id of max count.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for some reason I tried using .item() and manage to extract the exact value I needed.

In your case it would look like:

```
return census_df[census_df['COUNTY'] == census_df['COUNTY'].max()]['STATE'].item()
```